# Get all elements of XML with elementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

How Can I get all elements of an XML tree? The following code gives the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'. Is there a way to load it all into a dictionary?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

tree = xml.parse('strategies.xml')
XML = tree.getroot().findall('Strategy')
print (self.XML.items())
```

Comment: XML is already a list, isn't it the list you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no built in function to load the xml into a dictionary. It would be impractical because they can not know which element or attribute will be your key and value. But you can iterate on it and can make your own dictionary simply using :

```
for child in XML :
    print child.tag, child.attrib
```